# Combine state with IO actions

Tags: haskell, state, monads

Suppose I have a state monad such as:

```
data Registers = Reg {...}

data ST = ST {registers :: Registers,
              memory    :: Array Int Int}

newtype Op a = Op {runOp :: ST -> (ST, a)}

instance Monad Op where
 return a    = Op $ \st -> (st, a)
 (>>=) stf f = Op $ \st -> let (st1, a1) = runOp stf st
                               (st2, a2) = runOp (f a1) st1
                            in (st2, a2)
```

with functions like

```
getState :: (ST -> a) -> Op a
getState g = Op (\st -> (st, g st)

updState :: (ST -> ST) -> Op ()
updState g = Op (\st -> (g st, ()))
```

and so forth. I want to combine various operations in this monad with IO actions. So I could either write an evaluation loop in which operations in this monad were performed and an IO action is executed with the result, or, I think, I should be able to do something like the following:

```
newtype Op a = Op {runOp :: ST -> IO (ST, a)}
```

Printing functions would have type Op () and other functions would have type Op a, e.g., I could read a character from the terminal using a function of type IO Char. However, I'm not sure what such a function would look like, since e.g., the following is not valid.

```
runOp (do x <- getLine; setMem 10 ... (read x :: Int) ... ) st
```

since getLine has type IO Char, but this expression would have type Op Char. In outline, how would I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The basic approach would be to rewrite your `Op` monad as a monad transformer.  This would allow you to use it in a "stack" of monads, the bottom of which might be `IO`.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Registers = Reg { foo :: Int }

data ST = ST {registers :: Registers,
              memory    :: Array Int Int}

newtype Op m a = Op {runOp :: ST -> m (ST, a)}

instance Monad m => Monad (Op m) where
 return a    = Op $ \st -> return (st, a)
 (>>=) stf f = Op $ \st -> do (st1, a1) <- runOp stf st
                              (st2, a2) <- runOp (f a1) st1
                              return (st2, a2)

instance MonadTrans Op where
  lift m = Op $ \st -> do a <- m
                          return (st, a)

getState :: Monad m => (ST -> a) -> Op m a
getState g = Op $ \st -> return (st, g st)

updState :: Monad m => (ST -> ST) -> Op m ()
updState g = Op $ \st -> return (g st, ())

testOpIO :: Op IO String
testOpIO = do x <- lift getLine
              return x

test = runOp testOpIO
```

The key things to observe:

- The use of the `MonadTrans` class
- The use of the `lift` function acting on `getLine`, which is used to bring the `getline` function from the `IO` monad and into the `Op IO` monad.

Incidentally, if you don't want the `IO` monad to always be present, you can replace it with the `Identity` monad in `Control.Monad.Identity`.  The `Op Identity` monad behaves exactly the same as your original `Op` monad.

Comment: I realize (now) that the solution presented is standard, but this is a very interesting (and elegant) solution. Your rewrite of my code using a monad transformer was very helpful, since it provided a concrete example. Thanks!

Comment: A nice educational complement to Martijn's pragmatical solution.

Answer (score 37):

**Use liftIO**

You're already very close! Your suggestion

```
newtype Op a = Op {runOp :: ST -> IO (ST, a)}
```

is excellent and the way to go.

To be able to execute `getLine` in an `Op` context, you need to 'lift' the `IO` operation into the `Op` monad. You can do this by writing a function `liftIO`:

```
liftIO :: IO a -> Op a
liftIO io = Op $ \st -> do
  x <- io
  return (st, x)
```

You can now write:

```
runOp (do x <- liftIO getLine; ...
```

**Use class MonadIO**

Now the pattern of lifting an IO action into a custom monad is so common that there is a standard type class for it:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans

class Monad m => MonadIO m where
  liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

So that your version of `liftIO` becomes an instance of `MonadIO` instead:

```
instance MonadIO Op where
  liftIO = ...
```

**Use StateT**

You've currently written your own version of the state monad, specialised to state `ST`. Why don't you use the standard state monad? It saves you from having to write your own `Monad` instance, which is always the same for the state monad.

```
type Op = StateT ST IO
```

`StateT` already has a `Monad` instance and a `MonadIO` instance, so you can use those immediately.

**Monad transformers**

`StateT` is a so-called *monad transformer*. You only want `IO` actions in your `Op` monad, so I've already specialized it with the `IO` monad for you (see the definition of `type Op`). But monad transformers allow you to stack arbitrary monads. This what intoverflow is talking about. You can read more about them [here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/05/grok-haskell-monad-transformers.html) and [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers).

Comment: Your suggestions are all excellent, and I do realize that my 'op' monad is a specialized version of the state monad. But at this stage, I prefer to write the code myself, since it cements the structure and concepts in my head. However, thank you for bringing MonadIO, StateT, and so forth, to my attention.