# Can I have a monitor in XMobar that keeps state form one invocation to the next?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state-monad, io-monad, xmobar

##### tl;dr

I guess my question could be distilled to a Y/N question: *"Can the `IO` monad keep state only via I/O actions?"* In other words, is my understanding correct that if I have to write an action

```
run :: IO String
```

that is executed repeatedly by some other `IO` monad instance, there's no way I can write it so that it keeps memory, from a call to the next, of a state, other than by serializing the state somewhere (e.g. to file or in the caller if it offers an API to do so)?

But if the answer is *"Yes, you can't do that"*, then question is the one in the title: how can I write a monitor for XMobar which keeps a local state?

##### The full story

I'm experimenting with [xmobar](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar), and in particular with its [plugins and monitors](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org).

All monitors are run via `Run $ SomeMonitor` where `SomeMonitor` must be of type `Runnable`, i.e. it can be any type implementing the `(Exec r, Read r, Show r)` interface, of which [`Exec`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/src/Xmobar/Run/Exec.hs) is the interesting one, because it's where you put the business logic of the plugin, as it has type `IO String`, so it can create the `String` that is displayed by XMobar using `IO`.

Here was my first, very easy, experiment,

```hs
data ArchUpdates = ArchUpdates deriving (Read, Show)

instance Exec ArchUpdates where
  rate _ = 36000
  run _ = fmap (makeMessage . length . lines) $ getCommandOutput "checkupdates"
  where
    makeMessage :: Int -> String
    makeMessage = show -- simplified version
```

where I determine how many updates are possible via `pacman` on my ArchLinux system.

Now, clearly the value shown by XMobar changes over time, but *not* because it has an explicit dependency on time; it's because the state of the system changes, and the change is retrieved via an I/O action, expressed in the code above by `getCommandOutput "checkupdates"`.

But what if I wanted a plugin with an explicit dependency on time? I mean, a plugin that updates every second and shows, in turn, one of several strings? Say it shows first `"A long time ago"`, then `"in a galaxy far,"`, and finally `"far away..."`, and then loops again.

My requirement [makes me think of `State`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640120/combine-state-with-io-actions), but the `Exec` constraint is forcing me in the `IO` monad, so I don't think that the `StateT` transformer is the way to go, because I can't use *another* monad wrapping `IO` in `run`. I'd rather need `IO` to wrap some state... but I can't change `IO`!

Therefore the only way I see to keep state is for serializing it somewhere, and then re-reading it:

```hs
instance Exec MyPlugin where
  rate _ = 1000
  run _ = do
    old <- getCurrentStateOfSelf
    return $ makeNewState old
```

where `makeNewState` is `String -> String`¹, but `getCurrentStateOfSelf` should be provided by XMobar's API, otherwise what'd be left? Writing the state to a file?

```hs
  run _ = do
    old <- readStateFromFile
    let new = makeNewState old
    writeStateToFile new
    return new
```

This would be horrible.

---

I tried asking ChatGPT, and it gave me this:

```hs
import Control.Monad.State

func :: StateT Int IO String
func = do
  currentState <- get
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Current state: " ++ show currentState
  modify (+1)
  return "Hello, World!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (result, newState) <- runStateT func 0
  putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ result
  putStrLn $ "Final state: " ++ show newState
```

but I don't think that's a solution, because `main` is still in charge of making multiple calls to `runStateT` piping the state from one call to another; it's not like multiple calls *to* `main` are accessing successive states of `func`, which is what I'd want.

I guess probably the answer is that I'm hitting a wall: XMobar montitors have been designed in the `IO` monad whereas I'd need the `State` monad (then clearly XMobar would still use the `IO` monad to show stuff on screen, because after all it is a program, so it comes from compiling a `main` function, which is `IO ()`).

---

(¹) In the case of the 3 distinct strings above, it could be a closure with a `[String]` local `state` that takes a `String`, locates it in the `cycle state`, and gives back the item after that.

Comment: `run` is not a function; it's an IO action. In some sense, the only thing a Haskell does is produce an IO action (possibly from other, simpler IO actions) to be execute by the runtime. Other functions don't execute `run`; rather, combinators like `>>=` are used to *combine* `run` into more complicated actions which may evaluate functions as part of their execution.

Comment: I wrote "function" with reference to my at-the-top-of-the-post `run` because I had initially written as the `run` interface function of the `Exec` typeclass, so it was `whatever -> IO String`; and apprently I forgot to update the text. I've tried to reword a bit. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: Technically, you can use `runStateT` in your implementation of `run`, but as you note it won't do what you want -- the problem not quite being an incompatibility between the types, but that the `StateT` action, and the state you'd keep using it, would be bound to a single invocation of `run`, whereas you need it to persist beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach in [amalloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77893420/2751851) of initialising an `IORef` in the setup code and then making it available to the loop action is sound. However, as we have found out, by doing the initialisation in the `main` of `xmobar.hs` and trying to pass it through the plugin type we end up swimming against the current of the arrangement xmobar expects for its plugins. We can instead adapt the idea while implementing `Exec` in terms of `start` (`:: Exec e => e -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO ()`) rather than `run` (`:: Exec e => e -> IO String`), at the modest cost of having to lay down the updating loop ourselves. (The snippet below is partly based on [the `Date` example from xmobar's docs](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/commit/915b869896404d60bc6aa41c4c3c9311237595f2/doc/using-haskell.org#user).)

```
import Xmobar
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad (forever)

data MyPlugin = MyPlugin
  deriving (Read, Show)

instance Exec MyPlugin where
  start MyPlugin callback = do
    ref <- newIORef 0
    forever $ do
      output <- atomicModifyIORef' ref next
      callback output
      tenthSeconds 10  -- Wait one second.
    where
    next x = (x + 1, show x)

-- Then add MyPlugin to your config's commands and template as usual.
```

Incidentally, since `start` allows us to write the update loop, using `StateT` for the updates now becomes viable as well:

```
import Xmobar
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad (forever)

-- etc.

instance Exec MyPlugin where
  start MyPlugin callback = evalStateT loop 0
    where
    next = gets show <* modify' (+ 1)
    loop = forever $ do
      output <- next
      liftIO $ do
        callback output
        tenthSeconds 10
```

Comment: So I should have looked more carfully at the definition of `Exec`, understanding that `start` is what, with its default implementation, executes `run` periodically. So if I wanted to have state persist from one execution of `run` to the next, that state should be stored in `start`s closure.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope I'm really absorbing this stuff... Anyway, thanks to this, I now have a [crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_ticker) in my xmobar! Next on the list, trying to understand how to use xmobar to show notifications.

Answer (score 3):

It sorta depends. What is the API by which you give these IO actions to xmobar? If you can perform IO of your own to create an IO action, you can construct an IORef that lives outside of the IO action itself, for it to refer to and store data in. But if you can't interact with how xmobar starts, and all it asks you for is some `IO a` actions, you can't really smuggle an outside IORef in there (unless you cheat with `unsafePerformIO`).

But let's imagine that you are running xmobar yourself, and it returns some kind of IO action:

```
runXmobar :: [IO String] -> IO ()
runXmobar = undefined -- implemented by xmobar
```

Your `main` can look something like this:

```
main = do
  ref <- newIORef 0
  runXmobar [uptick ref]

uptick :: IORef Int -> IO String
uptick r = atomicModifyIORef' r next
  where next x = (x + 1, show x)
```

Here we've achieved what you asked for in your TL;DR question: an `IO String` action (`uptick ref`) that saves state locally to produce a different result each time it's called.

---

How to fit that into an `Exec` instance? It's not hard. duplode outlines it in a comment on this answer: store the IORef as a field in your object so that the `run` action can refer to it.

```
data MyPlugin = MyPlugin (IORef Int)

instance Exec MyPlugin where
  -- Read, Show, etc...
  run (MyPlugin r) = atomicModifyIORef' r next
    where next x = (x + 1, show x)
```

Construct this MyPlugin object in the `main` in your xmobar.hs, and include it in your `config`. You won't be able to define `config` as a top-level value anymore, because it depends on a value constructed in `main` by IO, but you can either define it in `main`, or make it a function taking a `MyPlugin` object as an argument.

```
main = do
  myplugin <- MyPlugin <$> newIORef 0
  let config = defaultConfig {
    -- ...
    commands = [
               -- ...
               , Run myplugin
               ]
  }
  xmobar =<< configFromArgs config
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how I can apply this to my usecase. [Here](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/etc/xmobar.hs) you can see an example, which shows how a plugin (the `data HelloWorld = ...` together with its `instance Exec HelloWorld where ...`) is used by xmobar. What would your `main` be? The `main` in there?

Comment: @Enlico Indeed. You'd add a field for the `IORef` to your `MyPlugin` type, initialise it in `main`, pass it as an argument to the constructor when defining the `Config`, and use it in the implementation of  `exec`. I guess we can't make that fit the usual way xmobar plugins are organised (no way to do it with only the `.xmobarrc` config file), but it should work fine as far as your `xmobar.hs` is concerned.

Comment: @Enlico I've expanded the answer to show what it looks like to use this in the xmobar.hs you linked.

Comment: @amalloy, I think I do follow your suggestion: `MyPlugin` wraps a mutable `Int` in `IO`, i.e. an `IORef Int`; that `Int` can only be modified by an `IO` action, such as `atomicModifyIORef'`, and that's ok, because the implementation of `run` is required to return an `IO` action, so we destructure `(MyPlugin r)` with `r` being the `IORef Int` and perform the action that  increments the inner `Int`; the inital value of that `Int` has to be assigned in `IO`, and we pass its wrapper, `myplugin` to `Run`. This all makes sense.

Comment: @amalloy, (cont.) But I'm having a really hard time implementing the `instance Read MyPlugin`, because `readPrec` has type `ReadPrec MyPlugin`, and it's not in `IO`, and I have no idea where to get a `MyPlugin` object out of an `IO` context. It feels to me that doing so would require some unsafe function, but I can't even think of what could be the right one. An impl that typechecks but makes no sense to me is `readsPrec i s = [(MyPlugin $ global i, "")]` (using `readsPrec` instead of `readPrec`).

Comment: @Enlico Oh, yeah, there's obviously no good Read instance for this suggested type. I wonder what xmobar uses Read for. It does seem to rule out this approach.

Comment: With any luck (I haven't actually tried it yet), it will only matter for parsing the `.xmobarrc` config file, and we'll be able to get away without a `Read` instance by compiling a custom `xmobar.hs` instead.

Comment: Update: we can avoid having to pass the `IORef' as a field of `MyPlugin`, and all the trouble that entails, by writing the instance of `Exec` in terms of `start` rather than `run`. With `start`, we can set up the update loop ourselves, and initialise the `IORef` before entering it. Cf. [this date plugin implementation example in the docs](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/using-haskell.org#writing-a-plugin) -- cc @Enlico